# Updating DataGridView with Linq on DB Change

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, linq, .net-3.5

I had a DataGridView using bindings to connect to a database. It was working nice, but we decided to change it to LINQ.

Before we changed to LINQ, the DataGridView automatically reflected any changes on the database. Every time a value changed, the DataGridView automatically updated its value.

Now we want to use a RELOAD - Button. On click, it would refresh the DataGridView and show the latest data on the Database.

I would like to show a symbol when there were changes on the database, much like here on StackOverflow, when there are changes on a question (it tells you there was a change).

What is the best way to accomplish this on LINQ? I thought maybe I would have to perform a database query (for example on a timer tick) and see if something changed. How can I accomplish this without using too much hardware resources?

DBMS: MSSQL 2005 or 2008

Comment: you have to implement a Timer wich can watch your DB if something happen then it will notify your UI

Comment: Yes, I just added the timer thing. But how can I watch my DB if something happened? We are talking of a couple thousand records on a single table.

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: MSSQL2005 (or 2008 if it has to be)

Comment: http://developergeeks.com/article/84/how-to-enable-database-change-notification-with-odp-net-and-oracle-11g-database

Answer (score 0):

you can use `OracleDependency` for notify the DB changes.

```
            OracleDependency oraDependency = new OracleDependency(selectCmd);  

            // Add the event handler to handle the notification.  
            // The oraDependency_Change method will be invoked when a notification message  
            // is received from the database.  
            oraDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(oraDependency_Change);

static void oraDependency_Change(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)  
    {  
    }
```

for more details you can refer the mentioned link [Click Here](http://developergeeks.com/article/84/how-to-enable-database-change-notification-with-odp-net-and-oracle-11g-database)